# OpenGL ES 1.1 iOS not sizing properly on retina versus non retina

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, drawing, coordinates

So, I'm having quite a bizarre issue and I'm not sure why. When displaying the following opengl code on a retina screen, I receive the following image: 
[image]

while the image I get on a non retina is the following: 
[image]

The coordinate system should be setup normally.. I also noticed that it doesn't seem to generally scale to retina size. When getting the frame from the [UIScreen mainscreen], I'm getting the same value for both retina and non as shown below. Is there a special way I'm suppose to size this?

```
frame: Origin: x:0.000000 y:0.000000, Size: width:768.000000 height:1024.000000
```

***Edit: The cause was that OpenGL ES 1.1 does not scale to Retina size by itself. When creating the ViewPort you must manually scale the size as such glViewport(0, 0, width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale], height * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]); 
This was the simplest method that I could come up with.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL itself doesn't know anything about the view or screen characteristics; it only knows about the pixels.

By default, and unlike other UIViews, a GL-backed view will not automatically use non-1.0 scale, and will instead operate at 1x. So as you discovered, you should set the screen scale to opt in to the retina pixel resolution (which is 2x the size in both dimensions).

However, increasing the number of pixels just increases the number of pixels. GL doesn't then magically know that it's supposed to scale all of your geometry (or in fact that that's what you really want). If you want to use the same geometry for both scale views (which you usually do), then yes, you are also responsible for applying the scale.

In ES 1.1 (which you seem to be using, this is just:

```
glScalef([UIScreen mainScreen] scale], [UIScreen mainScreen] scale], 1.0);
```

In ES 2.0, you'd apply this to your model-view or projection matrix, which you then use in the vertex shader to transform your input geometry.

Comment: Well, I didn't particularly need it this way (it definitely scales it though. I used glViewport(0, 0, width * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale], height * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]); to edit the Viewport to scale. I dislike the idea that I have to manually multiply by a scale, but whatcha going to do. I'm only reviewing the OpenGL ES 1.1 for more in depth knowledge. I know I've never had to worry about this in ES 2.0. So not too much of a concern anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 'scale' method for the view that apparently needs to be set to properly resize the view (as the view is position based rather pixel and for some bizarre reason, the positions don't resize with the increased resolution and such). This is the only thing I could really find. I've noted to include the following call check and set below within the init method of the GLView... but I'm still wondering if there's a better way. Wouldn't I manually have to resize everything by multiplying the height and width by the scale property?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    NSLog(@"frame: Origin: x:%f y:%f, Size: width:%f height:%f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        **if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: NSSelectorFromString(@"scale")])
        {
            if([self respondsToSelector: NSSelectorFromString(@"contentScaleFactor")])
            {
                [self setContentScaleFactor:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
                NSLog(@"Scale factor: %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
            }
        }**

        NSLog(@"frame: Origin: x:%f y:%f, Size: width:%f height:%f Scale factor: %f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height, self.contentScaleFactor);
        CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)super.layer;
        eaglLayer.opaque = YES; // set to indicate that you do not need Quartz to handle transparency. This is a performance benefit.

        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

        if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
            return nil;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I use setContentScaleFactor -- if you are on a retina device and you just want to render to the old non-retina resolution set that scale to 1 and iOS will double-size it for you.

Otherwise, if you write your code to detect retina devices and create a correspondingly larger viewport, setContentScaleFactor to 2 to be left alone by iOS.